# Copy files searched with find command using xargs command

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I'd like to copy the files searched using `find` command into the current directory. I am executing the following command-line:

```
    # find linux books
$ find ~ -type f -iregex '.*linux.*\.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 echo
    # Expected output on STDOUT
../Books/LinuxCollection/Linux_TLCL-17.10.pdf ../Richard Blum, Christine Bresnahan - Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible, 3rd Edition - 2015.pdf ..
```

I wish to copy the files to the current directory using the `cp` command. Here is the command that I entered:

```
$ find ~ -type f -iregex '.*linux.*\.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 cp .
```

However, I get an error as shown below upon executing the above command:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

I have also tried to resolve the issue by using command substitution. Here is the command that I tried:

```
$ cp $(find ~ -type f -iregex '.*linux.*\.pdf' -print0) .
```

However, I get another error as shown below upon executing the above command:

```
cp: Blum,: No such file or directory
```

How do I accomplish the desired result using the `xargs` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` appends its input to the command, so you are basically running `cp . source_file`. Use

```
find ~ -type f -iregex '.*linux.*\.pdf' -print0 | xargs -I '{}' -0 cp '{}' .
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you. I refer the manual page to the magic option `I`. Honestly very confused about its descritption.

Comment: `-I` is just used to define the character(s) to be replaced by the input afterwards. So `xargs` reads from stdin and then takes whatever it read and puts it where the `{}` is.

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish the desired result easily without using `xargs` command as shown below:

`find ~ -type f -iregex '.*linux.*\.pdf' -print0 -exec cp {} . \;`

Makes up for a simpler command line and doesn't involve piping.